# Чи можна вживати таке слово "помарка" у значенні "помилка/виправляння"?

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова, from-russian

Джерел які вказують на те що взагалі можливе таке слово "помарка" в українській мові мною не знайдено!

Але "гугл перекладач" [перекладає з російської](https://translate.google.com/m/translate?hl=ru#ru/uk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) на "помарка"...

Правильніше використовувати  "хиба/ виправлення"?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, що *помарка* - це російське слово, багато російсько-українських словників ([1](https://www.dictionaries24.com/ru/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC,%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) , [2](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53407/174147.html)) подають інший переклад - *корекція, ляпка, виправлення, поправка, пляма, побруднення, покреслення, мазання, креслення*; також у багатьох [російських словниках](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/221016/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) є його тлумачення. Хоча СУМ, все-таки, вживає це слово в якості [пояснення](http://sum.in.ua/s/nachysto) до іншого слова, та тлумачення саме *"помарка"* не подає. Стосовно онлайн-перекладачів, то вони часто можуть помилятись. На мою думку, найкращим варіантом є вживання слова ["виправлення"](http://sum.in.ua/s/vypravlennja).

Comment: не могли б ви уточнити, який саме "інший" переклад подають російсько-українські словники? треба всю важливу інформацію виносити у відповідь, бо посилання можуть псуватися, а користувачі не мають  перехоити за кожним посиланням, щоби дізнатися, про що саме ви пишете.

Comment: Звичайно, зараз добавлю.

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до [етимології](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) російського слова "помарка" воно походить від слова "марать", а в українській мові є схоже "марати" (пошуки цього дієслова в СУМі нічого не дали, тому сумніваюся у достовірності даної інформації,однак, можливо воно просто застаріле), а тому існування слова "помарка" теоретично можливе в нашій мові. Крім того в [Великому російсько-українському словнику](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-russian-ukrainian-bigruuk-term-85771.htm) я знайшов, що "помарка" й на українську може перекладатися так само.

Проте, в [Російсько-українському словнику](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53407/174147.html) від УАН бачимо такі варіанти перекладу: **побруднення, покаляння, покреслення; брудніння, каляння; мазання, креслення**.

А от ці два джерела ([1](http://www.unlimited-translate.org/uk/dictionaries/russian-to-ukrainian/translate/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0.htm), [2](http://www.%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0)) пропонують варіант "**виправлення**" як переклад слова "помарка" (з чим я погоджуюся адже згідно до російського визначення цього слова - це виправлення в написаному тексті, зроблене від руки).

Отож, теоретично існування слова помарка можливе в нашій мові (адже згідно до Вікіпедії схожі слова є і в польській, і в сербській мовах). Однак, краще замість нього вживати слова, які були наведені у відповіді.

Comment: «Марати» бачу як діалекте в [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=390).